# Raspberry does not use all the CPU

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, imacros, raspberry-pi2, iceweasel

I have a raspberry 2 (with raspbian), I installed Iceweasel and I added the addons iMacros.
I created a script in js, is really very slow, however, is only used 25% of CPU and less than 50% of ram.
Why it can not use all the resources? and complete the task in less time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are processing a single task on your raspberry pi.

The raspberry has a quad core processor ([product page](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-2-model-b/)).

Because a single task can only run on one core the same time, only 25% of the cores are fully used.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't count I/O. 
When OS runs from SD-card it can be much slower then you expect.

Try this :

`time /path/to/your/command args`

It will post something like this:

`real    0m1.096s
user    0m0.220s
sys     0m0.060s`

This will give you more info where is which portion of time is spent.

It is also possible to use

`strace -f -t /path/to/your/command args`

This will give you verbose output of system calls with timestamps

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `Raspberry PI 2` has a `quad-core` processor. Because `JavaScipt` doesn't allow multithreading you are limited by doing the work on one core. Therefore if one core is loaded 100% the whole processor is 25%.